# Angular 7 Transform Observable response to a new observable object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I have an api which responses like this and I am using rxjs observables

```
[{
  "error": "error_1",
  "types": [
     {
       "type": "new_type"
     },
     {
       "type": "old_type"
     }
  ],
  "date": "2019-08-29"
}]
```

I need to transform it into a new json format so i can get the response format i wanted.

I have tried pipe(map()) but i get error that Type '`Observable<void>`' is not assignable to type '`Observable<Error[]>`'

My Model

```
export interface Data {
    error: string,
    types: Types[],
    date: string
}

interface Types {
    type: string
}
```

My Service.ts

```
getError(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.http.get<Data[]>(url);
  }
```

This is what i tried so far and i deleted the code which produces error
My Component.ts

```
getUserErrors(user): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.getData.getError()
      .pipe(map((x) => x.filter(one => one.error !== null)))
}
```

Here is the observable output i need

```
[{
  "new_error": "error_1",
  "type_1": "new_type",
  "date": "2019-08-29"
}]
```

Thank you for those who will help

Comment: I do not see anything in your code that should produce the error.  I suggest you put together a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: is that supposed to be getError(): Observable<Data[]> {

Comment: @Pradeep yes. just a typo. I will edit it

Comment: Post the actual code, the actual error, and the precise line to which the error refers to. The error is about an Observable<Error[]>, and all the code you posted has nothing to do with Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to filter out the responses with null errors, then map the remaining elements to the new format, and return that as another `Observable`. You can use `flatMap` in order to chain multiple `Observable`s together:

```
getUserErrors(user): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.getError()
        .flatMap(result => {
            result = result.filter(elem => elem.error !== null)
                .map(elem => ({
                    new_error: elem.error,
                    type_1: elem.types[0].type, // since you want the first out of the two
                    date: elem.date
                }));
            return Observable.of(result);
        })
}
```

Later on when you call this:

```
this.getUserErrors(user).subscribe(
    result => { console.log(result); }
    error => { console.log(error); /* Do some proper error handling */ }
)
```

Comment: im getting Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Data[]>'.

Comment: @vashlor as I understand, `flatMap` is just an alias for `mergeMap`, so it might be that your version of rxjs doesn't recognize it. Try and use `this.getError().mergeMap(result => ...` instead.